# Can Pixy send image to a microcontroller like Raspberry pi and Raspberry pi?

Tags: image-processing, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm exploring CMUcam Pixy these days but I find that the existing API it provides is so limited. I want to do further image processing based on Pixy. Is there any method to transmit the original image data which pixy detects to a microcontroller like raspberry pi and raspberry pi?

Comment: So you want both Pixy's recognition data and it's image base? - To just grab images and do the processing on a Pi or the like, a webcam would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pixy camera was not intended for it. While it's possible to get images or streaming video by creating your own hardware-level API, the added complexity and time spent would be better served just using the official Pi Camera module which is natively supported and has a very friendly and robust API.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pi Camera seems to be a better choice to do image processing (it is ready to capture an Opencv object).

Comment: Just make sure to mark a question as answered so it gets taken out of the unanswered pool.